# Tabela com select e submit

Tags: php, mysql, select, table

Olá amigos estou tentando fazer uma tabela, sendo para cada item da tabela aparece um `<select>` e um `submit` que vai enviar dados via `POST`, como é relativo quantas unidades vai aparecer não é possível prever quantidades. Infelizmente da forma que fiz qualquer submit envia o último da lista e não seu respectivo.

É possível fazer essa ação?
Quais erros cometi?

Estou cogitando refazer todo código já que parece que fiz de uma forma errada, porém estou um pouco confuso.Alguém pode me dar dicas.

Segue alguns trechos do código.

Parte do corpo da tabela

```
   $query="SELECT DISTINCT `clientes`.`nome`, `ficha_de_moveis`.`id_controle` , `ficha_de_moveis`.`valor-total-controle`,`ficha_de_moveis`.`datamontagem`, `ficha_de_moveis`.`status` from `clientes` join `ficha_de_moveis` on `clientes`.`id_cliente` = `ficha_de_moveis`.`id-cliente`";
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $numero = $row['id_controle'];
        $cliente = $row['nome'];
        $sobrenome = $row['sobrenome'];
        $valor = $row['valor-total-controle'];
        $data = $row['datamontagem'];
        $data = date("d-m-Y",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));
        $status = $row['status'];
        echo"   
            <tr>
            <td>$numero</td>
            <td>$loja</td>
            <td>$cliente $sobrenome</td>
            <td>$valor</td>
            <td>$data</td>
            <td>
            <select class='form-control' name='statusm'>
            <option value ='$status'>$status</option>
            <option value=''>----------</option>
            <option value='APROVADO'>APROVADO</option>
            <option value='EXECUTANDO'>EXECUTANDO</option>
            <option value='CONCLUIDO'>CONCLUIDO</option>
            <option value='CANCELADO'>CANCELADO</option>
            </select></td>
            <td>
            <button type='submit' name='mudarStatus' class='btn btn-primary'>
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>&ensp;Montar
            </button>
            <a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' href='fichademoveiseditar.php?codigo=$numero&loja=$loja'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
            </td>
            </tr>";
    }
```

Metodo:

```
   if(isset($_POST['mudarStatus'])){

                            $mudar_status=$_POST['statusm[]'];
                            echo$mudar_status;
                            echo $controle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class='form-control' name='statusm'>
```

Todos os seus selects tem o mesmo `name`, por isso só o último é reconhecido. Você pode usar `name="statusm[]"` para enviar todos como um array (que é o que parece que seu código PHP está buscando) ou usar nomes dinâmicos baseados na identificação de cada um. Aí vai da sua preferência.

Caso opte pelo array, no PHP você poderá usar somente `$_POST['statusm']`.